# Cannot scroll with fixed subheader

Tags: ionic-framework, scrolltop

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/RangerRick/pen/MYJrOo)

```
<header>
<subheader>
<list>
```

It has a header and a fixed subheader and there are 1000  items on the list,

but I cannot scroll down the list, whenever I scroll, it will automaticlly scroll to top.